# Python: += strange behaviour in static method

Tags: python, class, object, static-methods

I've come across some strange behavior with +=, while learning about static methods.

Here is my code:

```
class Box:

    totalMass = 0
    def __init__(self, mass):
        Box.totalMass += mass

    def getMassconsumption():
        return Box.totalMass

o1 = Box(2)
o2 = Box(10)
print(Box.getMassconsumption())
```

As expected it returns the value:

```
12
```

However, when I change line 4 with:

```
Box.totalMass += 1
```

It returns the value:

```
2
```

Increasing the added value to 2, 3, 4 etc. gives:

```
4
6
8
```

Multiples of 2, regardless the input. Now I am pretty sure that I don't understand the code in my exercise book, nor how += works in this situation.
Could someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, indentation is rather crucial in Python.

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation.

Comment: You're adding `mass` (so, `2` and `10`), or you're just adding `1` (or `2`, or `3`) to `totalMass` each time… I'm really not sure what about this behaviour is confusing…!?

Comment: Sorry, I did indent the code in my file, it just did not show up here, but the same problem persists. I don't know what gets added to what in line 4

Comment: Where are you confused?  If you have +1 twice, you get a total of 2.

Comment: My understanding of the expression Box.totalMass += mass is:  Box.totalMass + mass right? But what is the value of Box.totalMass at the start and when is it given a different value? Sorry, but I just started learning this and the book I have does not have a good explanation for this

Comment: `Box.totalMass` is a class attribute, so it's shared by all instances of `Box`. Are you sure you want that? BTW, staticmethods aren't very common in Python, but when they are used, they're normally created using the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the code to

```
Box.totalMass += 1
```

each time you initialise a Box object, you're adding +1 to the value of Box.totalMass (and not using the value of the input at all). Since you initialise two boxes, o1 and o2, you're adding +2 to the initial value of 0, hence giving a total value of 2.

When you had

```
Box.totalMass += mass
```

you were adding the value of mass (defined in the initialisation of the object) to the total mass (that starts as 0).

Comment: Ah! Ok I get it now, I did not realize that it saved the previous value of Box.totalMass, each time I initialize the object. At least I think that is what is happening here? Thank you very much in any case!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening. Because you are calling Box.totalMass, it is the same value, shared across all copies of Box. If you want each one to have its own value, you could store it using self.totalMass in the class. Have a look here for more info : https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/